# find function inside vba code in excel

Tags: xml, excel, vba

I got the following xml file that is all in one row of text (multiple rows here to make it more readable):

```
<bla>
    <blabla>
        <moreblabla>
            <colheader>item1</colheader>
            <colheader>item2</colheader>
            <row>
                <col>apple1</col>
                <col>apple2</col>
            </row>
            <row>
                <col>pear1</col>
                <col>pear2</col>
            </row>
            <row>
                <col>grape1</col>
                <col>grape2</col>
            </row>
        </moreblabla>
    </blabla>
</bla>
```

I wanted to do the following, since I have no idea of the lenght of the blabla before the `<colheader>` I want to use the excel function find, in order to have the start character of the part that I am interested: the row col part of the xml file.

This is my preliminary script:

```
Sub replacexml()
Dim objFSO
Const ForReading = 1
Const ForWriting = 2
Dim objTS
Dim strContents As String
Dim fileSpec As String
Dim start As Long
Dim finish As Long
Dim lenght As Long

fileSpec = "C:\path\out.xml"
Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set objTS = objFSO.OpenTextFile(fileSpec, ForReading)
strContents = objTS.ReadAll

start = InStr(strContents, "<colheader>")
finish = InStr(strContents, "</moreblabla>")
lenght = finsh - start
strContent = Mid(strContents, start, lenght)

objTS.Close

Set objTS = objFSO.OpenTextFile(fileSpec, ForWriting)
objTS.Write strContents
objTS.Close

End Sub
```

But I got an error, I guess is not recognizing the Find function. How I get the find function to work?

UPDATE: now the mid function is having an issue:

```
  strContent = Mid(strContents, start, lenght)
```

Comment: As you are using VBA , use `Instr` . `Find` can be used as `Application.WorksheetFunction.Find` Read this : https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/worksheetfunction-object-excel

Comment: @asenav Be very careful, in the XML that you posted you close the `<bla>` before closing the `<blabla>` and the `<moreblabla>`. The last <> opened have to be the next closed one (I corrected in your post).

Comment: Thanks!  I have updated the part with the instr and I got no error there

Comment: I still have the issue of the Mid, the thing is that is failing but cant figure out why.

Comment: What is your end goal? Do you need to extract a value from XML? Create a smaller XML as a subset of this one based on a value? Please post desired result. You should not be using string finds on XML but XPath expressions.

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to find some text in a String, you can use `Instr`.

> https://www.techonthenet.com/excel/formulas/instr.php

Syntax

```
InStr( [start], string, substring, [compare] )
```

Hope it helps.

For `MID` function:

> https://www.techonthenet.com/excel/formulas/mid.php
>   Syntax

```
MID( text, start_position, number_of_characters)
```

You should define the start position and the number of characters, both should be numbers.

Comment: yes it help me!, now I am stuck with the Mid function.

Comment: Edited my answer... But not sure what "I am stuck" means.

Comment: the instr is giving me the right position inside the text string. But now the error is in the Mid function section, I have checked the syntaxis, but I have no idea why it stop there.

Comment: do you know how to debug your code to see the value of the variables?